# prevent tastypie from updating the foreignkey field

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a tastypie resource like

```
class MembershipResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')    
    activity = fields.ForeignKey(ActivityResource, 'activity')
    class Meta:
        authorization=Authorization()
        authentication=ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

Now, this works well when I do a post to this resource with data as

```
{
 user: "/api/v1/user/username/",
 activity: "/api/v1/activity/2/"
}
```

But, if I pass the full user data with username, id etc., TastyPie updates the auth_user and changes the authentication details (I cant login with the user till I reset the password in django shell)

Is there a simple way to make *fields.ForeignKey(ForeignResource)* to prevent updating the *ForeignResource*?

**EDIT:**

I can do it by using field-specific hydrate. For example:

```
def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
   user = UserNameResource()
   userbundle = user.build_bundle(data=bundle.data['user'], request=bundle.request)
   userobj = user.full_hydrate(userbundle).obj        
   bundle.data['user'] = userobj                
   return bundle
```

Or even by using a pseudo-field called user_id. But, I am of the opinion that this is a very common problem and there got to be a simpler way to do this through an option in field.ForeignKey.

Comment: can you not exclude specific fields in user table?

Comment: I need to link the existing user. So, I cant exclude the field. I have edited the question for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you do not want to update the user field, you can use the readonly param in the field.

```
user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', readonly=True)
```

Comment: I tried that option as well. The "readonly" option doesn't allow even to set the foreign key value of the resource.

Comment: Yes. If I pass just the resource URI, it is alright. But, if I pass a user object instead of an URI, the foreign field resource (in this case the User) is getting updated. I traced this update to "save_related" function of the ModelResource class. I will raise this issue in GitHub.

Comment: What is the github issue link. This seems like a security problem. Effectively a passing an id field to model with that existing record will wipe the existing record.